# Can anyone tell me a way to connect to Webspher MQ from cloud foundry using user provided services

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud

I am trying to connect to a Websphere MQ from pivotal cloud foundry and trying to see if it can be done using user provided service and spring cloud combination.

For example when i connect to a database in my spring boot application which is deployed on cloud foundry environment i use below steps

1. Create a user provided service which has oracle jdbcurl for database connection
2. By using below code spring-cloud  in configuration class we can obtain a datasource

   ```
   import javax.sql.DataSource;    
   import org.springframework.cloud.config.java.AbstractCloudConfig;
   import org.springframework.cloud.service.PooledServiceConnectorConfig.PoolConfig;
   import org.springframework.cloud.service.relational.DataSourceConfig;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

   @Configuration

   @Profile({ "dev", "qa" })

   public class DataSourceConfiguration extends AbstractCloudConfig {

       @Bean
       public DataSource dataSource() {
           System.out.println("RETURNING MY DATASOURCE FROM CLOUD PROFILE");
           PoolConfig poolConfig = new PoolConfig(5, 30, 3000);
           DataSourceConfig dbConfig = new DataSourceConfig(poolConfig, null);
           return connectionFactory().dataSource(dbConfig);

       }
   }
   ```

The same way i am looking for something where i can obtain a connection for my WebspherMQ . Is there any way to do?

Comment: You haven't given a lot of detail. What does spring-cloud have to do with it?

Comment: @spencergibb i have updated more details , please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user provided service instance is merely JSON stored as a "service instance" that can bind to and be made available to (via it's environment) an application instance.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html#create

It sounds like you might be hoping to bind an application to a WebsphereMQ instance without having to provide credentials yourself after manually creating an instance / queue manually. This would require using a service broker to create a service instance and also facilitate binding to that service. Documentation on creating a service broker can be found here:

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/api.html

I am not aware of a pre-existing broker for Websphere MQ.